# Quick search Bug results

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

im having trouble with the quick search results, i been looking in many posts, but none resolved by issue.

Im using mangeot search "combine" option, but still doesnt give me the result i need, for example, if i search for "Levis" the first results are "televisions" and after show the levis products, the search result is taking in consideration the letters between "televisions". So than i select "Full text" option, and than worked well, but the problem that i have when i search for "LG", it doesnt give me results beause in my title products i have "LG" betterrn other words on the title. I could resolve this issue using the "LIKE" option, but then the "Levis" wouldnt be resolved and show first the televisions, instead of Levis products. Someone have some kind of solution please?